# django заблокировать поле в форме

Tags: django

Как заблокировать(запретить редактирование) поле в форме(в шаблоне) при наличии там значения. ` 
Ниже код не срабатывает

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
<label for="id_tracc1" class="control-label">Account №1</label>
<input name="tracc1" value="{{ user.profile.tracc1 }}" type="text"
            class="form-control {% if value %} disabled {% endif %} " required
                                                       id="id_tracc1">
</div>`
```

Comment: Так Вы добавляете `disabled` к классу. Вы так и планировали?

Comment: Я не понимаю, в чём проблема сделать так: `<input {% if user.profile.tracc1 %} disabled {% endif %}>`

Comment: Супер спасибо работает !!!

Comment: Рад помочь :) Я перенёс комментарий в ответ. Если он Вам помог, Вы можете пометить его как верный, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете `disabled` к классу элемента, а нужно добавлять отдельным атрибутом.

***Пример:***

```py
<input {% if user.profile.tracc1 %} disabled {% endif %}>
```